# Sharing $scopes across Controllers with ScopeFactory

Tags: javascript, angular.js

Previously, I use to always navigate through the `$parent` `$scopes` in order to send or change data from one Controller into/in another. I then created my own `ScopeFactory` as a way to storing each Controllers $scope and then getting those scopes from other Controllers.

Having not experienced any problems with using this method, I'm just curious if this is a good way to do it.

```
.factory('ScopeFactory', [function() {

    var notifications  = { that: this };
    var tagsPanel      = { that: this };
    var activityHeader = { that: this };

    var saveScope = function(type, vs) {
        switch(type) {
            case 'notifications':
                notifications.that = vs;
                break;
            case 'tagsPanel':
                tagsPanel.that = vs;
                break;
            case 'activityHeader':
                activityHeader.that = vs;
                break;
        }
    };

    var getScope = function(type) {
        switch(type) {
            case 'notifications':
                return notifications.that;
                break;
            case 'tagsPanel':
                return tagsPanel.that;
                break;
            case 'activityHeader':
                return activityHeader.that;
                break;
        }
    };

    return {
        saveScope : saveScope,
        getScope  : getScope
    };
}]);
```

Saving a scope:

```
// inside activityHeader Controller:
ScopeFactory.saveScope('activityHeader', vs);
```

Getting a scope from another Controller:

```
var activityHeader = {};

activityHeader = ScopeFactory.getScope('activityHeader');
activityHeader.chosenTicker   = initTicker;
activityHeader.companyName    = compName;
activityHeader.currentPrice   = price;
activityHeader.currentPercent = percent;
activityHeader.initialTickerLoaded(ticker);
```

Comment: Personally, I think the best way to share scopes is to *not do it at all*. Any data that needs to be shared between controllers can and should be abstracted into services that maintain shared data. Controllers should be a dumb data-binding layer without any dependencies on other controllers. In my opinion, the very concept of sharing scopes is an antipattern.

Comment: Ah true... hmm that's a lot of new services/factories to create then in that pattern. Oh well I guess version 2.0 refactored hehe... So my way is sort of using a service to connect controllers. However a more better/separation of concerns way would be to have controllers communicate with connected services.

Comment: The idea is that a single service should encapsulate a single functionality related to data management. So if you have information about the currently logged-in user and some functions to interact with it, put that in a service. If you need to control application settings, put that in a service. If you need to interact with an AJAX API, put that in a service. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Finally figured it out, will post an Answer as to how to accomplish this in the true Angular way soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally refactored out the anti-pattern `ScopeFactory` out of my apps.

Instead I'm using `$broadcast` and `$emit` to accomplish what I'm trying to do, which is the more Angular way of doing this.

---

### Example

**Controller 1** (I $emit out the event and send a variable):

`$rootScope.$emit("add.ticker.typing", word);`

**Controller 2** (I listen for the event and pick it up, including variables like objects or strings):

```
$rootScope.$on(
    "add.ticker.typing",
    function handleSearchTyping(event, word, option) {
        if (option != 'empty') {
            typingSearch(word);
        } else {
            $scope.tickersList       = [];
            $scope.tickersListLoaded = false;
        }
    }
);
```

Now with this, now only is it a true Angular pattern, but I'm not sending giant Controller $scope objects all around my app.

Comment: Good. Now it's better